# Rails / Backbone - issues with using Underscore templates to link images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-4, underscore.js

I'm trying my first backbone + rails project and I'm stuck.  In my backbone views corresponding to a set of users, I'd like to display each user's avatar.  So in my html.erb file, I've got a template like this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="opponent_template">
    <img src = <%%= "assets/avatars/"+avatar+'_small.png' %> >
</script>
```

Which is fine in development, but in production on Heroku, that hard coded path is no good.  I gather it's because in production the filenames get their md5 fingerprints added.  Presumably it's also a very bad idea for me to try to work out what the post-fingerprinting filenames are and add those into my hard coding also.

I've tried to fiddle around with really ugly alternate code along the lines of:

```
<script type="text/template" id="opponent_template">
    <%= image_tag("avatars/" + <%%= avatar %> +".png" >
</script>
```

Which obviously doesn't work because the erb is evaluated server side way before the javascript is evaluated client side, and so this will never work.

Where to from here?  Is my code salvageable, or is there another templating solution that plays nicer with rails?  Do I need to get some sort of Javascript library to find the right url path for me?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using rails to pass a json object containing all the possible fingerprinted asset paths to backbone, for it to use in the template.  There's presumably an easier way, but this isn't too bad a solution at least.